# Prepared statement returns bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a simple api which adds views to a table. i've then tried to use prepared statements inorder to avoid SQL injections, but cant seem to make it work. It keep returning following error: `(Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in)`

```
$con = new mysqli('host','user','pass','db');
$type = $_GET['type'];
$identifier = $_GET['identifier'];
$news = $_GET['newsid'];

$check = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE news.news_id =? OR news.type =? OR news.identifier=?");
$check->bind_param("iss", $news, $type, $identifier);
$check->execute();


if ($check->fetchColumn() > 0) {

    $add_view = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO views VALUES (:news_id, :identifier, :type, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())");
    $add_view->bindValue(':news_id', $news);
    $add_view->bindValue(':identifier', $identifier);
    $add_view->bindValue(':ntype', $type);
    $add_view->execute();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing `mysqli` and `PDO` implementation here. You should use `bind_param` for `mysqli`. `bindParam` and `bindValue` are `PDO`s.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on warnings. You have an error somewhere in your syntax. So `$con->prepare` returns `false` and issues a warning.

You can find the text of the error in [`$con->error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).